# Wordpress Shortcode Code in Functions.php is throwing a Foreach Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, foreach, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-shortcode

I am getting the following error in one shortcode function that I use multiple times in different ways on my site. Only one of the functions causes an error.

We are using a combination of Wordpress, WooCommerce and ACF to display various linked ACF fields on each product page.

*Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /wp-content/themes/astra-child/functions.php on line 229*

It also doesn't show the Accessories in the correct area on the product page where the shortcode is used. Here is an example product page: https://mcdanielmetals.com/product/14-knocked-down-roof-curb-48/.

I have turned off the debug errors so users won't see them for now since it is a live site.

Here is the code that is throwing an error (I have added comments for which is line 229 where the `foreach` code is):

```
/* Product Accessories Shortcode [acf_accessories] */
function acf_accessory() {
    //if ( is_product() ) {
        //global $post;
        $prod_accessories = get_field('accessories' );
        
        if ( ! empty( $prod_accessories ) && ! is_wp_error( $prod_accessories ) ) {
            $accessory_links = array();

            foreach ( $prod_accessories as $prod_accessory ) { // LINE 229
                $accessory_links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link( $prod_accessory )) . 
                '">' . esc_html( $prod_accessory->name ) . '</a>';
            }

            return implode( ', ', $accessory_links );
        }
    //}

    return '';
}

add_shortcode( 'acf_accessories', 'acf_accessory' );
```

Interestingly I use the same code in three separate functions to create other short codes. These all are before the code above that is throwing the error and they are all working (notice they are all filled in in the example product above).

```
/* Product Applications Shortcode [acf_applications] */
function acf_application() {
    //if ( is_product() ) {
        //global $post;
        $prod_applications = get_field('application' );
        
        if ( ! empty( $prod_applications ) && ! is_wp_error( $prod_applications ) ) {
            $application_links = array();

            foreach ( $prod_applications as $prod_application ) {
                $application_links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link( $prod_application )) . 
                '">' . esc_html( $prod_application->name ) . '</a>';
            }

            return implode( ', ', $application_links );
        }
    //}

    return '';
}

add_shortcode( 'acf_applications', 'acf_application' );

/* Product Manufactuer Model Numbers Shortcode [acf_prod_mod_nums] */

function acf_prod_mod_num() {
    //if ( is_product() ) {
        //global $post;
        $prod_mod_nums = get_field('model_numbers' );
        
        if ( ! empty( $prod_mod_nums ) && ! is_wp_error( $prod_mod_nums ) ) {
            $mod_num_links = array();

            foreach ( $prod_mod_nums as $prod_mod_num ) {
                $mod_num_links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link( $prod_mod_num )) . 
                '">' . esc_html( $prod_mod_num->name ) . '</a>';
            }

            return implode( ', ', $mod_num_links );
        }
    //}

    return '';
}

add_shortcode( 'acf_prod_mod_nums', 'acf_prod_mod_num' );


/* Product Manufactuers Shortcode [acf_manufacturers] */

function acf_manufacturer() {
    //if ( is_product() ) {
        //global $post;
        $prod_manufacturers = get_field('manufacturers' );
        
        if ( ! empty( $prod_manufacturers ) && ! is_wp_error( $prod_manufacturers ) ) {
            $manufacturer_links = array();

            foreach ( $prod_manufacturers as $prod_manufacturer ) {
                $manufacturer_links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link( $prod_manufacturer )) . 
                '">' . esc_html( $prod_manufacturer->name ) . '</a>';
            }

            return implode( ', ', $manufacturer_links );
        }
    //}

    return '';
}

add_shortcode( 'acf_manufacturers', 'acf_manufacturer' );
```

The code is almost identical for each of these. I originally had all of the variables in each function set to the same variable name for each occurance but I changed them hoping it would fix the problem. I also moved the accessories shortcode function above the rest to see if something in the order of things was causing the problem but that didn't change anything either.

The only thing that I did to make sure the code works is change this line:

```
$prod_accessories = get_field('accessories' );
```

to another ACF field that is currently working:

```
$prod_accessories = get_field('manufacturers' );
```

I have quadruple checked the ACF fields above and they are both setup exactly the same. I am using the correct field id for both, but accessories doesn't show up.

The only other factor I can think of is that I recently moved the site to the live server from the dev site. The dev site still works with the same code so maybe something changed with the change in domain and server?

If anyone can help me track down why this one function doesn't work while the others do I would appreciate it.

Comment: Try `foreach ( (array) $prod_accessories as $prod_accessory )` or use `is_iterable()` before `foreach`. Also do a `var_dump( get_field( 'accessories' ) );` to check what type is returned.

Comment: Thank you! When I added '(array)' to that part of the function it worked! Not sure why it wasn't working before even though there are various similar functions that are showing correctly with out it. Should this be added to those just in case?

Comment: I have been spot testing and it works on some pages but others come back with this error.

'Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/customer/www/mcdanielmetals.com/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4494'

When this does appear some of the fields don't show up in the product info. Here's an example: https://mcdanielmetals.com/product/14-knocked-down-roof-curb-39/.

I haven't been able to find a pattern as to which products are affected (i.e. a specific accessory type).

Comment: I think your code above is fine now because you either return an empty string `return ''` or return a string you get from `return implode( ', ', $some_links )`. Apart from that, this is a very common issue in WordPress. I've often had it myself. It was almost always a plugin or the theme that was interfering or perhaps there are problems elsewhere in the custom code.